# How safe are disabled buttons in React?

Tags: html, reactjs, events, button, disabled-input

I just discovered that editing a button in developer tools to enable a disabled button changes nothing. The button somehow remains disabled internally. (Though the disabled style effects are removed)

```
//This is how the button looks like in Chrome developer tools

<button disabled>Post</button>

//editing out "disabled" does nothing. The click event doesn't get called
```

Interestingly, trying to disable an enabled button changes nothing as well. The onClick method still gets called when it's clicked.

Before my discovery, I always used a flag to block a click incase a malicious user enabled the button.

```
....
const [enabled, setEnabled] = useState(false)
....

....
const postData = () = {
   if(!enabled) return;

   //sensitive action takes place here
}
....

....
return(
    <button disabled={!enabled} onClick={postData}>Post</button>
);
....
```

I just want to know if it is completely safe to remove the `if(!enabled) return;` line from the `postData()` function. Are there other tools that could really enable a disabled react button or call `postData()` directly?

Comment: You can put the exact same code that decides if the buttons should be disabled within your event handler (and instantly `return` if it should). But if this is  a security issue, the general rule is to never trust what the front-end sends you, and to adapt your behavior server-side

Comment: @Treycos Isn't that what I'm doing in the example or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`disabled` button are as safe in React as they used to be in HTML. Ultimately what Browser understand and gets is DOM elements and React rendered on a Browser is no exception to this. That said never rely on front-end alone for any security and have server-side validations and security checks as well.

Comment: I see. So you're saying having the flag there or not makes no difference and it's never safe?

Comment: Yes, indeed. You can never rely on it 100%.

Comment: It's scary how easily modifiable front-end code for web is. I wonder if mobile and desktop app developers have to worry about things like this.

Comment: Yeah, they mostly do. most of their security measures are on their backend